# Could not read from remote repository (bitbucket)

Tags: ubuntu, repository, bitbucket, repo

Unable to open bit bucket from browser.

Getting below message while connecting from command prompt in ubuntu20.04.

$repo init -u ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.com:7999/yyy-zzz/manifests.git -b main -m xxx_zzz11.xml

ssh: connect to host bitbucket.xxx.com port 7999: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
manifests: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.xxx.com port 7999: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: cannot obtain manifest ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.com:7999/yyy-zzz/manifests.git

Comment: So you don't have access at all in browser to http/s:bitbucket.xxx.com:7999 or only to that specific yyy-zzz/manifests? If you have no access at wall it could be a networking restriction, firewall or something else that should be managed by the network guys, if you can access the server but have not access to that specific repo, contact the you BitBucket admin to provide permissions. Once those are fixed, if still have this issue could be the case you didn't add the public key in BitBucket as you are trying to use ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much self explainable:

Potential issues:

- Your local SSH keys are wrong or have not been set up in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
- There is no ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.com:7999/yyy-zzz/manifests.git repository on a server.
- Repository exists, but there is no branch "main" in it.
- Repository exists, brunch is availble, but there is no manifest file xxx_zzz11.xml in it.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Issue not related pub, because I can connect successfully when I have connected office network.Getting this issue when I am home network with a VPN connection